# How to concatinate string with multiple complex SELECT statements and place it in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a scenario where I'd like to get columns with information stored in a very specific way. 
I'd like to select n number of columns from a table A, concatinate their values, and then add m number of more values which should be grabbed from other tables by joining one of their columns to the current statement's column.

- Cars - (car_id, model_id, plate_id, brand_name, year_of_release, **custom_column**)
- Model - (model_id, model_name, description)
- Plates -  (plate_id, car_owner_name, registration_state)

Let's say we have these tables and what we want to do is place the following information in one column:

```
'car_id, brand_name, year_of_release, plate_id, model_name, car_owner_name, registration_state'
```

for each row of the Cars table as a '**custom_column**' value

I'd like it to be a comma-separated string. Is there a way to do this with MySQL?

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(', ', car_id, brand_name, year_of_release, plate_id, model_name, car_owner_name, registration_state)
from t;
```

Comment: @NataVacheishvili a table

Comment: That is exactly what I needed